# How do I add attribute names to vertices in a graph in R

Tags: r, social-networking

here is my code

```
d <- read.csv("dataset.csv")

s_network <- graph_from_data_frame(d[,2:3], directed = FALSE)

plot(s_network)
2:3 are source:target nodes
```

I'm new to R I want to know how to add attribute names which is present in 4th column of my dataset

Comment: What is the format of your dataset?

Comment: Are you trying to set vertex attributes, edge attributes, or attributes of the overall graph? Check out e.g. `set_vertex_attr`: http://igraph.org/r/doc/set_vertex_attr.html

Comment: (Vertex_id,Source,Destination,Attribute) @vektor

Comment: I want the vertex attributes to be displayed in graph @mikeck

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to add labels to your graph look at the `set_vertex_attr` help file as suggested by mikeck, this is the example given.

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(10) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("label", value = LETTERS[1:10])
g
plot(g)
```

which results in:

[image]

Also from an adaptation of the `graph_from_data_frame`help file here is another option:

```
relations <- data.frame(from = c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
  "David", "Esmeralda"), to = c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", 
"Alice") )

my_names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David", "Esmeralda")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed = FALSE, vertices = my_names)
plot(g)
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: what is the code if I want to refer the attribute column in dataset for vertices names

Comment: @Anirudh You can do the following, `relations <- data.frame(from = c("Bob", "Cecil", "David", "Esmeralda"), to=c("David", "Esmeralda", "Cecil", "Bob"), names = c( "Bob", "Cecil", "David","Esmeralda"))`
`g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations[,1:2], directed = FALSE, vertices = relations[,3])` but this only works if the number of edges is the same as the number of vertices, I think you are much better storing your vertex attributes elsewhere as suggested in the `graph_from_data_frame` help file.